# How to auto start a a href="javascript:void window.open( open loading

Tags: javascript, html

```
<a href="javascript:void window.open('website', 'pukarock', 'width=1018, height=715, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes');">click me</a>
```

How do you auto start this in HTML as `onload`? Other stuff I researched doesn't work. I only want my website to open up in a new window and has to work with blogspot.

Comment: ahhh! pop-ups! *My browser is shaking it's fist at you as we speak*

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a script block, not an A-tag.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.open('website', 'pukarock', 'width=1018, height=715, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes')
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `href="javascript:void"`

It means people without javascript cannot use the link. Use something like this instead.

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/" onclick="openNewWindow(this.href); return false;">Click</a>
```

Then add this to the head of your page

```
<script>
  function openNewWindow(url) {
     window.open(url, 'pukarock', 'width=1018, height=715, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes')
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want open page after load content, use this:

```
<!--use some standards of html-–>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="openSite();">
<script type='text/javascript'>
function openSite()
    {
        window.open('website','pukarock','width=1018,height=715,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
    }
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

But it could show pop up window warning.